# Ubuntu core ask for password when using ssh keys

Tags: ssh, ubuntu, password

Can someone tell my what is wrong when I try to login into my raspberry with SSH:

Debug info:

[image]
[image]
[image]
I have followed this guide ubuntu guide for ubuntu core and for ubuntu ssh keys. Can see on google that a lot of users have this issue.

Thanks,
Nenad

```
nedad@Dragic-Home-I:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv nedad@192.168.1.136
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.136" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.136 [192.168.1.136] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nedad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.136:22 as 'nedad'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/nedad/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/nedad/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.136
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
```

Comment: Please post text, not images. Nobody can read this

Comment: I get an error that I am poisting spam.

Comment: Let me try again:

Comment: Now with out any errors;)

Comment: Generate a new key, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine when I create a key with PuTTYgen.
So it works fine now.

Thans for yours help,
Nenad

Comment: You can accept your own answer to this question -- otherwise it will remain unanswered and re-appear in the feed over and over and over...

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the `PreferredAuthentications` key in your servers (Pi) `/etc/sshd/ssh_config` by adding the line

```
PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

and then restarting the ssh-daemon (`sudo systemctl restart sshd`) or just rebooting.

You could also try to log in with this option added to the ssh command and explicitly specifying the private keyfile (normally located at `~/.ssh/`)

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -i [path/to/your/key] nedad@192.168.1.136
```

Comment: Trying to use the ssh preferredAuthentication I receive "Permission denied (publickey,password). What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

As seen from the debug log there is an identity file `/home/nedad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert` used for authentication. The log doesn't show that it is denied or accepted and have not finished messages. You should paste the complete log output to the question.

B.t.w., using a private keyfile for authentication like you do, it is normal that it is protected with a password to use it. This is not a password to authenticate against the ssh server. It is only a password to enable the key file to be used to authenticate against the ssh server. If you do not want to enter a password you can clear it on the keyfile with a security risk. Then everyone getting this keyfile is able to get into your ssh server.

You can clear the password on the keyfile with:

```
rpi ~$ ssh-keygen -p
```

This will then prompt you to enter the keyfile location, the old passphrase, and the new passphrase, which can be left blank to have no passphrase.

**reference:**
[How do I remove the passphrase for the SSH key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/5014688)

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this for others running into this issue that are not using Putty. In Putty you have to specify or load the key that you want to use. If you are connecting via the terminal then it will assume that you want to use `id_rsa` as the key since this is the default key. If you specified a name when you created the ssh key then you will need to specify this on connection. e.g:

```
ssh -i ubuntu-one_rsa user@ip-address
```